# Cygwin64 | mount: Invalid argument

Tags: windows, mount, usb-flash-drive, cygwin

I am trying to do simple operation using my USB flash card and Cygwin64:

```
mkdir /tmp/sdb
mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp/sdb
```

And get following error:

```
mount: /tmp/sdb: Invalid argument
```

How to resolve this problem? Tried different file systems for my USB flash card but it didn't work.

P.S. I am following the tutorial about installing software on Wi-Fi Router.

It says:

0. Put software files on USB flash drive, formatted as fat32;
1. Connect to your router by SSH using MobaXterm;
2. `traceroute ; /bin/sh`
3. `mkdir /tmp/sdb && mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp/sdb && cd /tmp/sdb`
4. `mount`
5. `dd if=mtd12 of=/dev/mtdblock12 && dd if=mtd1 of=/dev/mtdblock1 && dd if=mtd0 of=/dev/mtdblock0`

On 3. I am getting error as described. I can use another terminal, for example, from MobaXterm, but nothing changes and I am getting the same error.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to use Cygwin for?? :) .. Your router is running Linux.  When you ssh into the router, you are ***IN LINUX*** (in the router).  Are you using MobaXterm?  Does it actually log into the router?  Your question is all wrong.  People here will need the model of the router, the firmware you are upgrading to, and possibly screen shots from MobaXTerm.  Rewrite Question:  (something like) Unable to upgrade firmware on Linksys x22-r3 router.  With the screen shots and the like, someone should be able to help you (possibly me).

Comment: @Angelika what is the output of `cat /proc/partitions` ?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is not unix nor a unix virtual machine.
All of the rules of Windows still apply.

First format the USB stick in windows using a windows file system (NTFS, Fat32, etc).

Drives that get mounted in windows will magically appear under your `/cygdrive/` folder and not `/dev/sxxx`.

Once windows can see your USB drive, look in the `cygdrive` folder for it as it will already be mounted becuase Windows mounted it and Cygwin reflects that change here.

[Here] you can find the use of the Cygwin `mount` command and you will notice that there are no refrences to `/dev/xyz`.

If you are using Cygwin just for fun and to learn, I highly suggest using the Windows Subsystem for Linux or an actual Linux VM instead.  If you are using it because you have to, then it is what it is.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I don't understand, what should I change in this command to make it work. Edited the question to be more clear in my goal.

Comment: Moving comments back to your question at the top.